# Google People API contactGroups.list not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I am trying to retrieve a simple JSON file with label names + resource names from Google Contacts using Apps Script, for which I have written the following:

```
function getAllMemberships() {
    var request = People.People.contactGroups.list('people/me',{
        groupFields: 'name'});
    Logger.log(request.contactGroups);
}
```

But keep receiving the same error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')

For the second line of code.
I have activated the People Service (identifier 'People') and given all permissions, but have no clue why the method does not work. Any advice/lead?

Comment: Have you enabled the People API

Comment: @Veztar. It appears that `.contactGroups` do not seem to exist in the **People** advanced services in Apps Script but `.ContactGroups`. Have you tried something like the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
function getAllMemberships() {
    var request = People.ContactGroups.list({
      "groupFields": "name"
    });
    Logger.log(request.contactGroups);
}
```

***Guide/Reference***: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people

***Sample***: [Result Logs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usXKI.png)

Comment: @Veztar Hope this works on your end.

Comment: This does it, thank you!